# Cannot convert DateTime object to string

Tags: php

I am trying to generate date (after 7 months from now)
here is my code

```
$cdate = new DateTime("+7 months");
$cdate->modify("-" . ($cdate->format('j')-1) . " days");
$expiry_date= $cdate->format('Y-m-d');
$expiry_date = strtotime($expiry_date);
```

which gives the error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:
  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

it is working with be before ... what is the problem??

Comment: Are you sure that error in those lines? http://3v4l.org/VAFii

Comment: Where did you initialize $moe?

Comment: Works fine for me - http://codepad.org/oR33GWGN

Comment: sorry it is $ex ... I just updated the Question

Comment: @NabilKadimi yes it is working until you use strtotime

Comment: @ManMann - Why are you converting it into a string, then back to a timestamp? Why not simply `$cdate->getTimestamp()`?

Comment: @ManMann, still working http://codepad.org/LpX7LsOO ... What PHP version do you have?

Comment: oooh ... something weird here ... I moved the last line and but it before some lines of code and it is working fine

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class has no magic method [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring), so you cannot use this object as string.

You should use [getTimestamp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

```
$cdate = new DateTime("+7 months");
$expiry_date = $cdate->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cdate = new DateTime(+7 months);
$cdate = $cdate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Will cause cdate to be a string if that's what you are going for.